# Codeigniter 3.1.9 MY_Form_validation is not working

Tags: codeigniter

Im working on Codeigniter 3.1.9 and completed my form on local machine. i just uploaded my app some moment ago on server and getting error

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name
>   URL.(valid_url_format)

i google alot but unable to fix problem.

Filename: My_Form_validation.php
Location: application\libraries

```
    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{

   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
    }                           

    function valid_url_format($str){
        $pattern = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
                if (!preg_match($pattern, $str)){
            $this->set_message('valid_url_format', 'The URL you entered is not correctly formatted.');
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }        

    function url_exists($url){                                   
        $url_data = parse_url($url); // scheme, host, port, path, query
        if(!fsockopen($url_data['host'], isset($url_data['port']) ? $url_data['port'] : 80)){
            $this->set_message('url_exists', 'The URL you entered is not accessible.');
            return FALSE;
        }               

        return TRUE;
    }  
}
```

Filename: UrlChecker.php
Location:application\controllers

```
        class UrlChecker extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {

            parent::__construct();

        }

        public  function _initializing(){



        }

        public function index()
        {



            $this->form_validation->set_rules('link', 'URL', 'required|trim|valid_url_format|url_exists');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
            }

            else

            {

    echo 'ok';

    }

}
```

Please check and let me know whats wrong is there hosting version problem or there is something else.

Answer (score 0):

I always use custom validation on the fly and its the first time to try to make a custom library for additional validations, anyways i created and tested it to make sure it works, you got to make sure you follow the naming convention, the file name should be like this: `MY_Form_validation.php` and save it in your `application/libraries` then create your class:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation
{
    // your rules
}
```

then you have to create error messages for every method, create a lang file in your `application/language/english/form_validation_lang.php` and add your custom error messages like this:

```
$lang['valid_url_format'] = 'The {field} field may only contain valid url.';
$lang['url_exists'] = 'The {field} field already exists';
```

Comment: i did same you can check i already explain paths and full class mention but no luck

Comment: its working fine on localhost but not working when i upload on live server

Comment: Are you using CI as it is or with hmvc extension?

Comment: im using CI just downloading from codeigniter.com Version 3.1.9.

Comment: You loaded `form_validation` in your controller/model or in autoload?

Comment: yes i did other default validation working fine expect only MY_Form_validation is not working.